# Sip_ua package - "Call initialize before setting the stream" error when attempting to make a call

Tags: flutter, sip

I am currently working with the sip_ua package in my Flutter application to implement SIP functionality. However, I am encountering an error when attempting to make a call. The error message I receive is:
`Call initialize before setting the stream`

I have cloned the example from sip_ua package and used the asterisk test server.

I expected the SIP call to be initiated without any issues. However, the error mentioned above occurs.